# passing index value to use as a selector in jquery

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

REVISED EDIT as of 4/28. I must have some selection error.

An updated jsFiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/thumbslinger/UwFRm/44/

What should happen, is that when one clicks on a ".correct" answer, the corresponding "rightAnwer" should become visible. This is the snippet from the fiddle that isn't working:

```
$('.correct').click(function(){
     var findMe = $(this).parent().parent().index();
    $('.answer').eq(findMe).show();
     });
```

The correct "answer" is being shown, however, I just want the div with the class of '.rightAnswer', which is a child of 'answer' to show.

//////////// ORIGINAL POST BELOW //////////////////////

killing me. NOTE: I asked something similar but the issue now is passing a value versus getting the value. I'm wondering if using eq() is an issue w/show/hide.

This returns the value I need:

```
var findMe = $(this).parent().parent().index();
```

Now I am trying to use that value as part of a selection for another element:

```
$('.correct').click(function(){
   var findMe = $(this).parent().parent().index();

   $('#fullSongs_Container .answer:eq(findMe)').show();
     });
```

and I've tried:
$('#fullSongs_Container .answer').eq(findMe).show();

So, I'm wanting to use the same index value of the first line as a filter when choosing another div in a different container.

Comment: There has to be a better way to do this than your relative `parent().parent()` approach.  Do you have some HTML to share?

Answer (score 4):

Change your code

```
$('#fullSongs_Container .answer:eq(findMe)').show();
```

TO

```
$('#fullSongs_Container .answer:eq(' + findMe + ')').show();
```

If you did not understand what I did. 
In your existing code, "findMe" is just a string and not a variable. In the modified code, findMe is treated as a variable and it's value will be substituted there.

Comment: hmm.. I'll have to try that... it doesn't seem to work just yet...background and other graphics not here, but here's the whole thing so far: http://jsfiddle.net/thumbslinger/UwFRm/  btw, on the first and second question, the second answer is correct

Comment: @lbreau did you fix the problem ? I did not suggest 2 answers, I just said your existing code (the first one, in my post) should be modified ( the 2nd one is the modified code)

Comment: yes, I tried that but it still show() the correct answer, however setting a css style works so I think eq() and show/hide is a possible issue.

Comment: did you check what the value of findMe is ? If it's fine, then please setup your code on jsfiddle.net, it'll be easier to debug.

Comment: ok, I put up a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/thumbslinger/UwFRm/8/   clicking on anything "correct" at the left should then show the corresponding answer to the right. Thanks for the help

Comment: lbreau, it does highlight the correct answer. What is your requirement ?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out for future reference. My selector was off. In the nested pattern of:

```
<div class="question">
  <div class="rightAnswer"></div>
  <div class="wrongAnswer"></div>
</div>


$('.answer .rightAnswer').eq(findMe).show();
```

is what I needed.

Though jquery reads from right to left in terms of selection, this threw me off because I considered the eq() and show() to be part of the right-to-left actions to take rather than thinking just of the selections then the actions to take.

Everyone here probably knows that but now I see.